Outline Shader in object with multiple materials
I'm new with shaders, and I was watching a tutorial to add outlines to my model.
The tutorial was perfect, but I got a problem.
That shaders works with objects with one material, in my case, I have a model with 4 materials, and the shader works only with one material (I need to add the outline shader to the material array, and in my case, it detects only the last material)
Can anyone guide me to apply this outline to all my materials?
This is the video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=U51yrbgBmAo
(just the outline part 0:37 to 2:22)
I also tried another tutorial with a coded outline, but the result was the same, it only takes one material (in this case the hair material)
This is how it shows now: only the hair have the outline example

The object the tutorial shows at https://youtu.be/U51yrbgBmAo?t=166 pretty much has multiple materials itself ... the shader is pure vertex based so it shouldn't care about other materials ..

Yeah, it have multiple materials, but the outline only affect the body material (the struct of the model itself helps a lot cause the other materials are from the face and he don't need the ouline in the face)

Again as said: The outline doesn't work on / care for materials but purely works on the mesh vertices - there are no lines in the face of pikachu because because there is no vertex edges there in the mesh ...

Well in the tutorial video the object already has 4 materials on it so I don't really see a problem. (as you can see in 2:45 in the video)
your problem is probably due to something else, try repeating the video and see if you did everything Exactly the same before making any changes, and make sure you watch the complete video :)

Yup, as I responded to the other comment, that's right, it has 4 materials, but if you notice (I downloaded that same model) the outline affects only one (which is in fact the body material, l The other materials are from the eyes, mouth and handkerchief, and it does not affect them, I watched the entire video more than 4 times). Anyway, I found another solution, that method only works for one material
